# Why doesn't this create a file on the destination server?

Tags: powershell

I recently did a storage migration and we had about 700 files that failed to migrate out of around 7 million (we need to purge some files, I know).  I wrote the script below that is supposed to look at the corresponding file on the destination, compare the date values and if the file doesn't exist or has an older date, it's supposed to copy it over.  Unfortunately, it's not copying it over.  I don't get any errors but the file doesn't land on the destination.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, I originally tried to grab the entire directory but it choked on the volume of files so that's why it parses each directory in turn instead.

```
$toplvl = "D:\Users\"
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $toplvl -Directory
$file = ""

$folders | ForEach-Object {
$original = $_.FullName
$dest = $_.FullName.Replace("D:","\\NewFileServer\D$")
$OutputFile = $_.FullName.Replace($toplvl,"D:\filelist-")
$FirstFind=0 #used to create a header in the output file

# Get all files under $original, filter out directories
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $original | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }
Write-Host $original #write directories to host to track progress


$filelist | ForEach-Object {

    ## Check if the file (from $original) exists with the same path in $dest
    If (Test-Path ($_.FullName.Replace($original,$dest) ) ) {

    ## the file from $original has a match in $dest

        $file = Get-Childitem -Path $_.FullName.Replace($original,$dest)
        If ($_.LastWriteTime -gt $file.LastWriteTime) {
            ## file from $original is newer than $dest
            If ( -Not ($FirstFind)) {Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "Original File, Date"}
            $FirstFind = 1

            Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $_.FullName -NoNewline
            Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "," -NoNewline
            Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $_.LastWriteTime

            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $file.FullName
            }
        else {
            ## file from $original is same or older than $dest; can remove else statement
        }
    }
    else {

    ## the file from $original is missing from $dest
    If ( -Not ($FirstFind)) {Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "Original File, Date"}
    $FirstFind = 1

    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $_.FullName -NoNewline
    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "," -NoNewline
    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $_.LastWriteTime
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($original,$dest)
    }
}
}
```

Hopefully I didn't mess this up copying it over - it's my first time posting and I'm still figuring out the formatting.

Comment: what you describe is better done with robocopy. PoSh simlply aint all that good with large numbers of files ...

Comment: Can robocopy compare file dates?

Comment: Yes, it can. `robocopy /?` from a command prompt. There are also existing questoins that have been answered here about using robocopy for this sort of thing (compariing dates and only copying if there's a difference, etc.) that you can find with some searching.

Comment: @terry - yes, as `Ken White` pointed out, robocopy can do that. it is a basic requirement to do what RC is designed to do ... [*grin*]

Comment: I didn't realize it had the capability.  I probably could have saved quite a bit of time working on this code.  I'll check out the switches for it.  Thanks

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you for this - robocopy is much easier.  I wish I'd known about the extra switches that it has.  I probably should have known at this point in my life.  I don't know how to mark your response as the answer or if that matters on this particular site

Comment: @terry - my comment doesn't really Answer your Question ... it gives a different approach to the problem. your "thank you" is quite enuf ... and much appreciated. [*grin*]